# Java error - no permission to save a txt file

Tags: java

I made a Java app (netbeans) and some times the app needs to save a txt file on computer (on the same app folder).

If I put the app on a desktop folder, the program works Great.

Now I used inno setup to create a simple install on program files folder with an app link on desktop, and the app gives an error (Java permission error).

Everytime it needs is to save the txt file on this folder (program files\app\file.txt).

Is this a inno setup problem or can I fix it with some Java programmer lines ?

Comment: No, it's a design issue. Applications shouldn't save files in the folder where they're installed. They should either ask the user where to save files, or, if the data they save is temporary, use temporary files, or at the very least save files in some folder under the user's home folder. `Program Files`, or `/usr/bin`on Unix platforms, are for programs. Not for data.

Comment: Well  donne. So, cause this is a Windows app i think i must use the documents folder, instead. Correct?

Comment: @Playdiune For Windows, if the file shouldn't clog up their Documents folder (*i.e.*, it isn't an actual document), you can make a folder inside the `%APPDATA%` folder and save things there. As the name partially implies, it's for application data specific to a particular user, which is nice since it lets different users set things up with your app in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by JB Nizet:

> No, it's a design issue. Applications shouldn't save files in the folder where they're installed. They should either ask the user where to save files, or, if the data they save is temporary, use temporary files, or at the very least save files in some folder under the user's home folder. `Program Files`, or `/usr/bin`on Unix platforms, are for programs. Not for data.

and Chai T. Rex:

> @Playdiune For Windows, if the file shouldn't clog up their Documents folder (*i.e.*, it isn't an actual document), you can make a folder inside the `%APPDATA%` folder and save things there. As the name partially implies, it's for application data specific to a particular user, which is nice since it lets different users set things up with your app in different ways.

I solved the problem by saving data on Documents folder.